# DropDownList Initial Value Duplicated - MVC 5

Tags: drop-down-menu, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a `@foreach` in my View that makes a table. Each row has two items within it's `td`. When I click my Edit button, the visible item's in a row disappear (`DislayFor`'s) and the hidden items in the row appear (`DropDownList`)

**View Code**

```
        <td class="col-md-3">
            <span class="item-display">
                <span style="font-size: 17px">
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Movie.Name)
                </span>
            </span>
            <span class="item-field">
                @Html.DropDownList("movieID", item.Movie.Name)
            </span>
        </td>
```

By doing this I can select a new value in the `DropDownList` and then Save that change to my Database (then hiding the DropDownList and unhiding the DisplayFor.

Everything works fine, however I have an issue with the initally selected value, it appears twice with the initial value having an actual `value` of 0 (which relates to nothing in the DB).

Picture Example
[image]

**QUESTION:**

Right now my dropdown *add's* a value upon clicking Edit, the item initially selected has the correct name but it is given the index of 0 (which is invalid for my database).

I want to have the initially selected item to NOT be added, but rather to set the selector of the dropdown to the CORRECT INDEX of the appropriate item. I am not sure why it duplicates my selected item twice.

**Controller Code**

```
public ActionResult Index(string Filter, string searchString)
{

    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString) || String.IsNullOrEmpty(Filter) || (Int32.Parse(Filter) == 0))
    {
        ViewBag.employeeID = new SelectList(db.Employees, "ID", "Name", );
        ViewBag.movieID = new SelectList(db.Movies, "ID", "Name", initiallySelectedValue);
        ViewBag.roleID = new SelectList(db.Roles, "ID", "RoleType");
        var movieemployees = db.MovieEmployees.Include(m => m.Employee).Include(m => m.Movie).Include(m => m.Role);
        return View(movieemployees.ToList().OrderBy(x => x.Employee.Name));
    }
    else
    {
        ViewBag.employeeID = new SelectList(db.Employees, "ID", "Name");
        ViewBag.movieID = new SelectList(db.Movies, "ID", "Name");
        ViewBag.roleID = new SelectList(db.Roles, "ID", "RoleType");



        var parameter = Int32.Parse(Filter);
        return View(db.MovieEmployees.Include(m => m.Employee).Include(m => m.Movie).Include(m => m.Role).Where(x => (parameter == 1 && x.Movie.Name.Contains(searchString)) || (parameter == 2 && x.Employee.Name.Contains(searchString)) || (parameter == 3 && x.Role.RoleType.Contains(searchString))).Distinct().ToList().OrderBy(x => x.Employee.Name));
    }

}
```

Comment: I've read your question three times and it's still not exactly clear what you're asking (at least to me).  I see you're using `DropDownList` and are seemingly just passing a single string to the method.  How are you getting all of those other options as pictured in your question?

Comment: @JustinHelgerson I am new to MVC, but I "think" this line here `"movieID", item.Movie.Name` is saying to take all items from my **Model** in `movieID` and to place them in there and to get the appropriate string names from `item.Movie.Name`. (db.Movie.Name)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your understanding of the parameters for `DropDownList` isn't quite correct, but you're close!  The second parameter for `DropDownList` (in your case `item.Movie.Name`) is adding an `option` label.  If you replaced that with a hard-coded string that would serve as a good example of what it's doing (you would see that string as the first option of every select input).

It sounds to me like you want to delete that last parameter since it will only end up serving as a duplicate.  Your code would simply look like this:

```cs
@Html.DropDownList("movieID")
```

The *important* part of your code is where you're building the object that you're storing in `ViewData` with the key `movieID`.  You didn't post your controller code, but I imagine it looks something like:

```cs
var movies = movieRepository.GetAllMovies();
ViewData["movieID"] = new SelectList(movies, "Name", "Id", initiallySelectedValue);
```

Where `Name` and `Id` are the names of properties on the movie object and `initiallySelectedValue` is rather self explanatory.

### Edit

Here is an example of how I would go about solving your problem:

**Controller**

```cs
public ActionResult Index() {
    //Get all the possible movies that can be selected
    var movies = movieRepository.GetAllMovies();
    //Get a list of employees with their related favorite movie record
    var employeesWithFavoriteMovie = movieRepository.GetEmployeesWithMovie();

    var employeeModels = new List<EmployeeModel>();

    //Iterate through the list of employees and their favorite movie, and build the model
    foreach (var employeeWithFavoriteMovie in employeesWithFavoriteMovie) {
        employeeModels.Add(new EmployeeModel() {
            FirstName = employeeWithFavoriteMovie.FirstName,
            FavoriteMovieId = employeeWithFavoriteMovie.Movie.Id,
            MovieSelectList = new SelectList(movies, "Name", "Id", employeeWithFavoriteMovie.Movie.Id)
        });
    }

    return View(employeeModels);
}
```

**View**

```cs
@model IEnumerable<WebApplication1.Controllers.EmployeeModel>

@foreach (var employeeModel in Model) {
    @Html.DropDownList("Test", employeeModel.MovieSelectList)
}
```

Notice how a `SelectList` was built for each employee and that each list is then populated with that employees *current* favorite movie id.  This will now put you in a position to have a properly built `SelectList` for each employee.

Comment: Ah that makes much more sense! However I am still a little fuzzy on how on how to do the `initiallySelectedValue`. Right now as expected when I click edit it displays dropdowns with the selected value as the first value of each field, whereas I would like the dropdown to keep the current index that it is at.

Comment: I also added my Controller's Index() code if that helps!

Comment: @Austin It's only using the selected value as the first field because you're adding a default option to the select list that happens to be the movie name.  Just as an example, change `item.Movie.Name` to `"AustinTheStormtrooper"`.  You'll start to see what the second parameter is actually doing.  It isn't setting the *selected value*, it's adding a default option.  If you want to do this properly, you'll actually need to build a `SelectList` for *each employee*.  This way each select list will know what their currently selected favorite movie is.  I can provide some code to help if needed.

Comment: I already removed the optionLabel as you suggested in the answer. By doing this, it now set's the initial value to first value of each list. What I am trying to do now, is somehow set that initial value to   be whatever the previous value was. So if the Name was Commander Rex, and I wanted to Edit this, I want the dropdownlist to have the indexed value for Commander Rex, right now it just shows whatever the first value of the list is. That make sense? I added my Select List in the question as well ^

Comment: I am basically trying to do what you said to, `ViewBag.employeeID = new SelectList(db.Employees, "ID", "Name", "employeeID");` but I am not sure how to format this to set the selectedValue to each employee.

Comment: @Austin I understand what you're trying to do, but how you're going about it isn't going to work.  Right now you're only building *one* `SelectList`.  That won't work because each `SelectList` needs to be aware of what the currently selected value should be.  That selected value differs from employee to employee, so what you actually need to do is build a `SelectList` for **each** employee.  See the edit to my question for an example of how to solve the issue.

Comment: Ohh okay, I shall what I can do with that. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.classmasterd_HCF[i].TD_TEACHER, new SelectList(Model.Teacher, "ParamKey", "ParamValue", Model.classmasterd_HCF[i].TD_TEACHER) as SelectList, new { @class = "form-control input-sm DtlField EditableCtrl", @style = "min-width:100%;", @disabled = "disabled" })
```

where Teacher in `Model.Teacher` is a model with code in paramKey and description in `paramvalue`. Selected value saved in `TD_TEACHER` field